# Angular 1.5 UI not updating till user makes another input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

So im building a pretty simple chat App with Signal R and Angular however im having an issue where basically the UI wont update until the user makes an input IE clicks into the input box or clicks out of it or presses a key

Here is one of the functions that add to the messageboard

```
hub.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
    $scope.messageBoard.push(message)
    var element = document.getElementById('messageBoard')
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight
}
```

Here is the website http://coolkidschat.azurewebsites.net/Home (excuse the name, just something random that poped into mind), it's much easier to see what's happening if you just enter a message and press enter you'll notice how nothing will change untill you press another key or click out of the box.

I've tried using `$scope.$apply` but that dosent appear to br doign anything so I've removed it

Edit: just to make it clear on how a message is sent.

User enters message -> sends to Server -> server sends too all clients -> angular appends it to the page

Edit: also just noticed i broke else something on my last publish, working now though

Comment: what specifically is supposed to happen/update that is not happening/updating?

Comment: The message should appear in the box, updated the post with a flow of how a message is sent

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to help without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @typologist I can post the code, but im not sure what part would be doing it specifically. I put the function above that appends to the maint part of the page that you can see the messages, which is where it is interacting with angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.$apply()` fixes it for me, and it should - your code is being executed outside of Angular's digest cycle. Just place a `$scope.$apply()` at the end of that method. In the debugger, that fixes the issue on my end.

Comment: Oh yeah that's working now, maybe I had another issue at the time when i was trying to use `$scope.$apply()`. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.$evalAsync()` to execute an expression on the scope, during the current cycle or at a future point in time. So try:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function() {
    $scope.messageBoard.push(message);
});
```

Comment: Would that be better than using `$scope.$apply()`? which appears to be fixing my issue now

Comment: @Toxicable, please see this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2751-scope-applyasync-vs-scope-evalasync-in-angularjs-1-3.htm

Comment: None is better, just depends on your needs. The good thing about $evalAsync is that it' will try to evaluate your expression during the current digest cycle if possible, otherwise during the next one.